# SQL2008 - Change Data Capture

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is anyone currently using the new Change Data Capture Feature in SQL2008?  We are starting to research and wonder if this should be used versus the trigger method.

If you have experience with this feature, any pros or cons would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,

Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're in the early stages of replacing lots of triggers with CDC; so far no surprises, works great, vastly improved performance. Biggest gotcha is being aware of the size potential of the change files; many of our updates are many single column updates so we wind up with 40 or 50 before and afters in the change table.

Overall looks very promising.

Comment: We are going forward with them, but it is a single table with only a few columns.  I still prefer the triggers.  I would only have a couple of triggers and one table.  Much less overhead for this scenerio, but we are experimenting with CDC.  Another gotcha is that when you disable the CDC on a table, the history tables are dropped and you lose your history.  No warnings, your tables are just gone.

Comment: Agreed on your gotcha...our one gotcha so far is restoring databases with CDC enabled requires an extra parameter if sa doesn't own it.  That and watching space used on those change tables.